# Excel: How to find a range, from a list of ranges, that a value is in?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I hope someone can answer my question!

I have lots of values and need to know which ones lie within a list of ranges and if so which range they lie in.

For example worksheet 1 contains my values of interest in column A while worksheet 2 contains the start value of ranges in column B and the end value of the ranges in column C and a name for each of these ranges in column D. How would I find out if a value given in worksheet 1 column A is between any range described in worksheet 2 column B to column C and return the corresponding info from column D. Essentially finding out what range covers by value of interest.

p.s. finding a range within a range would be even better if anyone knows how to do it, but I gave up on this a while ago!

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous websites that discuss double matches and similar formulas in more detail and more efficient ways to do this but here is one examples.

Assumptions:
2 sheets

- Sheet 1 = data
- Column A = Borehole
- Column B = Depth
- Column C = Value calculated from sheet 2
- Sheet 2 = ranges
- Borehole
- Depth From
- Depth To
- Value (used to fill sheet 1 column C)

the formula is an array formula which means it needs to be entered using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>

`=INDEX(ranges!$D$2:$D$5,MATCH(data!A2,IF(data!B2>ranges!$B$2:$B$5,IF(data!B2<ranges!$C$2:$C$5,ranges!$A$2:$A$5,""),""),0))`

I won't go into how index and match work as that is all over the web but for the inside of the match formula this is what is going on.

The two **if** functions check whether your given depth is between each depth from and depth to value.  If it doesn't match both of these criteria it returns a blank, if it does match both it returns the borehole ID from column A.

The match function then attempts to match your wanted well id against an array which includes some good id's and a bunch of blanks.  If it matches the well id this is the row you are after and it returns this value to the index which selects the corresponding value cell.

For matching ranges it depends if the ranges line up or which ranges are longer as you could be trying to fill a value into a range that crosses multiple bins.