# Find where a mileage range falls within a list of setranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

This is my first post and not sure on the various etiquettes so apologies in advance if I have done it wrong!

I have a list of mileage ranges I'm going to call '8ths'. For example, one range is `004.0880 - 004.0110` representing a 220yd range. I have given each range a corresponding number (the one just mentioned is no. 48)

I then have a list of mileage ranges of where work took place e.g. `004.1091 - 004.1095`. I need to know which mileage range this work belongs to from the first list. Ideally, when I enter the formula it would categorise the mileage range as 48 for me allowing me to group these jobs together.

I've been trying to do an INDEX(MATCH formula with an IF statement contained within the MATCH but am really struggling.

I found [this threadat SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/778034/excel-how-to-find-a-range-from-a-list-of-ranges-that-a-value-is-in) which looked very similar to what I'm trying to do, but I haven't quite been able to replicate it to work. I'm slightly confused by what the lookup value for the MATCH is in my case. When I go into 'show calculation steps', the formula seems to be working out that the range should be categorised as 48 but then gives a N/A# error at the next step.

Worksheet1:

```
Column A - Start mileage of job
Column B - End mileage of job
Column C - cell where I want the '8ths' range to be populated
```

Worksheet2:

```
Column A - 8ths numbers
Column B - Start mileage of 8ths Range
Column C - End mileage of 8ths Range
```

Let me know if you need any more information.
Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Are values of mileage ranges in "8th" placed in _ascending order_? If yes, when there is 50 mileage ranges in "8th",  the headers in first row, you may try: **=LOOKUP(,0/(data!A2>=ranges!$B$2:$B$50)/(data!A2<=ranges!$C$2:$C$50)/(data!B2>=ranges!$B$2:$B$50/(data!B2<=ranges!$C$2:$C$50),ranges!$A$2:$A$50)**.

Comment: Hi Emily, thanks for the reply. The ranges are in ascending order so I tried that formula you gave but it gave an N/A# error. Looking at the calculation steps it sems to start working through the rows but then ends up with a load of DIV/0 errors. Below is my formula with my sheet.
=LOOKUP(,0/(I2>='8ths'!$B$3:$B$1760)/(I2<='8ths'!$C$3:$C$1760)/(J2>='8ths'!$B$3:$B$1760/J2<='8ths'!$C$3:$C$1760),'8ths'!$A$3:$A$1760)

Comment: sorry, I missed a right bracket in formula. you may try **=LOOKUP(,0/(I2>='8ths'!$B$3:$B$1760)/(I2<='8ths'!$C$3:$C$1760)/(J2>='8ths'!$B$3:$B$1760)/(J2<='8ths'!$C$3:$C$1760),'8ths'!$A$3:$A$1760)**. I made a [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHLD6.jpg), the result like this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUcMZ.jpg). But when the values of Sart mileage and End mileage belong to different ranges, the result will be #N/A.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks so much. I should have noticed the brackets! 
Ah ok, thanks or pointing out. Any way to easily highlight which ranges it sits between in that situation? Using an ISNA or something?